# So I have a container with 3 divs that I want to style in the container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-selectors

So I have a container with 3 divs that I want to style in the container the first div goes on the top left the second is a picture div meant for the right of the container the third is a caption title with social media buttons that go under the first div but they're spaced out. I want the first div to be on the top left of the container with some margin so its not directly on the edge its a combination of a div with span tags inside, the second is an img that is meant for the right of the container and the last div is meant to be spaced under the first div

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.right-img {
  order: 2;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.left-top {
  order: 1;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.left-bottom {
  order: 3;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#text1, #text2, #text3 {
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-media-title {
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons a {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.buttons a:hover {
  color: #1c87c9;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .right-img {
    order: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .left-top {
    order: 2;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .left-bottom {
    order: 3;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left-top">
    <div id="typewriter">
      <span class="text-1">Hi, I'm</span>
      <span class="text-2">Adam</span>
      <div class="text-3">I'm a <span class="typing"></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-bottom">
    <p>Find Me On</p>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href=""><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-img">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="adam-mohamed-web-developer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the display `flex` of the container to display `grid` and use `grid-template-areas` to place each object where you want them to be. Also assign a `grid-area` to each div because that is what will be used to assign its area.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/83n0pwcf/6/

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr, 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    'left-top img'
    'bottom-left .';
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.right-img {
  order: 2;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  grid-area: img;
}

.left-top {
  order: 1;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  grid-area: left-top;
}

.left-bottom {
  order: 3;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  grid-area: bottom-left;
}

#text1, #text2, #text3 {
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

.social-media-title {
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.buttons a {
  align-items: flex-start;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.buttons a:hover {
  color: #1c87c9;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .right-img {
    order: 1;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .left-top {
    order: 2;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
  .left-bottom {
    order: 3;
    flex-basis: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
    <div class="left-top">
      <div id="typewriter">
        <span class="text-1">Hi, I'm</span>
        <span class="text-2">Adam</span>
        <div class="text-3">I'm a <span class="typing"></span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-img">
      <img src="image.jpg" alt="adam-mohamed-web-developer">
    </div>
  
  
  <div class="left-bottom">
    <p>Find Me On</p>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button>icon 1</button>
        <button>icon 2</button>
        <button>icon 3</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```